# How to replace the deprecated window.event on a generic function call?

Tags: javascript

I have a generic function to copy values to the clipboard. There are 2 optional parameters, 1 for what should be copied, and 1 for what should be displayed in a small notification.

If the first optional parameter isn't passed, it defaults to the content on the element that fired the event. This is done by accessing the "window.event.target.innerHTML" property but that is displaying warnings as window.event is deprecated.

I also, elsewhere, trigger this function through other JS by just calling "CopyToClipboard('foobar')" for example.

I understand that for a bound event the event property is passed as the first parameter but I am calling this by onclick in the HTML which doesn't have the event parameter.

```
<div onclick="copyToClipboard()">No parameter</div>
<div onclick="copyToClipboard('Foo')">Parameter defined</div>
<div onclick="copyToClipboard('Foo', 'Bar')">Parameter defined, message defined</div>
```

```
window.copyToClipboard = function (text, message) {
    if (text == null) {
        text = window.event.target.innerHTML; // This is deprecated
    }
    if (message == null) {
        message = '"' + text + '"';
    }
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    console.log('Copied ' + message + ' to clipboard'); // Display notification
}
```

I have setup a JSFiddle to test in a small scale environment : https://jsfiddle.net/ueLf8g0t/4/

This has 2 versions of the function but the one with the event parameter doesn't actually contain an event parameter.

Comment: the answer given is correct.. I just want to add that in case you kept the inline event handling, you would have solved the issue by calling your function passing `this` as argument like: `onclick="readClickedElement(this)"`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to rely on `window.event` when you do not use inline event listeners in your HTML. Instead, use the `.addEventListener` method to attach your listeners.

```js
function copyToClipboard(text, message) {
    if (message == null) {
        message = '"' + text + '"';
    }
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    console.log('Copied ' + message + ' to clipboard'); // Display notification
}

function readClipboardParams(el) {
  let params = el.dataset.clipboardParam.trim();
  return params === ''
    ? [el.innerHTML.trim()]
    : params.split(',');
}

function handleClick(event) {
  let params = readClipboardParams(event.target); // <--
  copyToClipboard(...params);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.clipboard-listener').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```html
<div class="clipboard-listener" data-clipboard-param="">No parameter</div>
<div class="clipboard-listener" data-clipboard-param="Foo">Parameter defined</div>
<div class="clipboard-listener" data-clipboard-param="Foo,Bar">Parameter &amp; message defined</div>
```

If you cannot do it this way or just don't want it, an obvious solution would be to just write the parameters in you HTML:

```js
window.copyToClipboard = function (text, message) {
    // This cannot happen anymore
    //if (text == null) {
    //    text = window.event.target.innerHTML;
    //}
    if (message == null) {
        message = '"' + text + '"';
    }
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    console.log('Copied ' + message + ' to clipboard'); // Display notification
}
```

```html
<div onclick="copyToClipboard('No parameter')">No parameter</div>
<div onclick="copyToClipboard('Foo')">Parameter defined</div>
<div onclick="copyToClipboard('Foo', 'Bar')">Parameter defined, message defined</div>
```